# Expansion and photon decay

Tags: general-relativity, photons, space-expansion

We know that there are two types of photon "decay", not destruction, but loss of energy and resultant lengthening.  ONe type is due to great gravitational pull and the other is due to the expansion of space-time.

Where do cosmologists believe the energy disappears to in space-time expansion?  Since energy cannot be created nor destroyed, cosmologists or other theoretical physicists/astronomers must have a valid explanation for that.

Comment: *We know that there are two types of photon "decay", not destruction, but loss of energy and resultant lengthening.* What do you mean by this? Photon decay would be a process in which a photon turned into other particles. See, e.g., Julian Heeck, "How stable is the photon?," http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2821 . Could you edit your answer to clarify what you have in mind?

Comment: Both your examples are incorrect. In a gravitational redshift, the photon does not lose energy, but is emitted already with a lower energy, which doesn't change in flight. In space expansion (assuming no acceleration), there is no redshift, if the photon's frequencies at emission and absorption are measured in the same frame of reference. However a photon can lose or gain energy in an interaction with a macroscopic object, such as a moving mirror.

Comment: Ben:  In Astronomy it is well known that a photon escaping a very strong gravitational field loses energy ( and thus a lengthening).  It is my belief that the photon continues to lose energy to infinity however small that amount might be once it has escaped far beyond the gravitational field, however as long as it is close, say within a few radii of a black hole's boundary, it would lose energy in relation to 1/r^2.  Safesphere has a different opinion which is very interesting and I never knew about that.

Comment: Ben:  the other type of energy loss is due directly to the expansion of space.  As space expands, the photon is "stretched" basically and loses some of it's energy.  My question is, where does that energy go?  It is an important question and I thimk it is directly relevant to 'why' there is space-time expansion and sheds light (ho ho, not meant to be a pun) on many other questions that have not been answered about the actual nature of light and matter.

Comment: Safesphere:  But the very point is that we are NOT in the same reference and no matter which direction we point our light detectors, we see the same redshift which is attributed to spacial expansion.  I think it is well accepted that this expansion is what caused the initial loss of energy of the now very cool light left over from the big bang.  Also, about the light emitter at a lower frequency I cannot help but thimk that is wrong due to the fact that gravity attracts light in it's path as shown with Eddington's test of Einstein's theory in 1919.

Comment: Ben:  My mistake, I was using the term "decay" as in the more general meaning not as in particle decay.  I meant the loss of energy and lengthening of it's wave length.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply that there is no absolute conservation of energy in a time-dependent cosmology (such as expanding universe).  While energy conservation is very well tested on "local" scales, its validity on the scale of the cosmos has never been verified, and in general relativity, the conservation law can fail.

Comment: THis is understandable and may be the answer, however, I feel that it is just a cop-out for not having a theoretical answer.  it is my belief that the decay of photons (and maybe other particles) fuels space-time expansion at the Planck level

Comment: @Donito Not only this answer is a cop-out, but also is incorrect. Let Buzz give an example of the energy loss due to a non-accelerating space expansion, as measured in one frame of reference.